# In Puppeteer how to capture Chrome browser log in the console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm trying to collect Chrome browser logs: browser-issued warnings such as deprecation and interventions. For example, for site https://uriyaa.wixsite.com/corvid-cli2:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://wix.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute.
A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.
You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

I thought the following code would do the trick but it only catches logs generated by the page code.

```
(async ()=> {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({dumpio: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('console', msg => {
        for (let i = 0; i < msg._args.length; ++i)
            console.log(`${i}: ${msg._args[i]}`);
    });
    await page.goto('https://uriyaa.wixsite.com/corvid-cli2', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 20000});
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

bellow is not relevant as I thought as reportingobserver does not catch the chrome info on cookies without sameSite:
Reading on the subject led me to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/reportingobserver but I'm not sure how to use it, using the example int the browser console didn't work.

I'm not sure in which context the observer code should be used or if the browser need a flag to activate the reporting API. Or if this is the way to got about it.

help is welcomed.

Comment: ReportingObserver is enabled since Chrome 69, no need for a special flag. Maybe it works only if the site response has Reporting-Endpoints HTTP header (you can spoof it in puppeteer, look for examples)? Also try [Log.startViolationsReport](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log/#method-startViolationsReport) if puppeteer supports it or allows sending raw protocol commands.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm , could you elaborate on "the site response has Reporting-Endpoints HTTP header" not sure what it means

Comment: This is an HTTP response for the (main) page URL when you do page.goto. To spoof these headers I guess you would use puppeteer's [request](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-request) class. Look for examples around.

Comment: ok so i've learned the reportingobserver will not report on such things as cookies without sameSite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, the `'console'` event only catches `console.log()` and similar calls from the pages. But it seems you can catch warnings from the browser via [`CDPSession`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) with [Log Domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log/). Unfortunately, it works for me only with a headful browser:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();

    await cdp.send('Log.enable');

    cdp.on('Log.entryAdded', async ({ entry }) => {
      console.log(entry);
    });

    await page.goto('https://uriyaa.wixsite.com/corvid-cli2');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

And one of the entries:

```
{
  source: 'other',
  level: 'warning',
  text: 'A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://www.wix.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.',
  timestamp: 1589058118372.802,
  url: 'https://uriyaa.wixsite.com/corvid-cli2'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had been pulling my hair out (not much left) with LaunchOptions. Btw, what do the brackets do? as in const [page]

Comment: Also, how do i get the web browser to close automatically after the entries get returned? I added await browser.close() but the code exited before the entries get returned.

Answer (score 3):

When you launch Puppeteer browser, inside the options object, you should set `dumpio` to `true`:

```js
await puppeteer.launch({ dumpio: true });
```

This will basically "pipe browser process stdout and stderr into process.stdout and process.stderr", which means it will redirect browser logs to whatever main process, server, etc. you are running.

You can see this and other launch options you can use when launching Puppeteer in here: https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.LaunchOptions.html

Comment: I've followed this and it means nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it means nothing"? If it doesn't work for you, it doesn't mean that it won't work for others. Don't downvote answers just because they don't work for you :) If you give more information about your use case, maybe others or myself can help you solve it.

Comment: It's solved by vsemozhebuty. Thanks.